# Use explode in a generator function to iterate over a long string in PHP

Tags: php, string, iterator, generator, explode

I'm using a PHP function to parse a very long string (output of shell_exec command). Currently, the function is like below and works fine.

```
 /**
 * @param string $result Output of shell command
 * @return array $lines each line of output in array
 */
public function getLines($result)
{
    $lines = [];
    $expl = explode(PHP_EOL, $result);
    foreach ($expl as $line) {
         $lines[] = $this->funcFormatLine($line);
    }
    return $lines;
}
```

Now, I'm starting to use [generators in PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) and that function looks like a good use case to refactor using it, because the array of explode output is big and consumes some memory.

What I want:

```
/**
 * @param string $result Output of shell command
 * @return string $line one line of output until end_of_line
 */
public function getLines($result)
{
    $line = fancy_func_to_get_all_before_end_of_line_without_array(PHP_EOL, $result);
    yield $line;
}

//somewhere in the function    
foreach (getLines($result) as $line) {
    doThings($this->funcFormatLine($line));
}
```

In the first case, I had two arrays with a lot of info (`$expl` and `$lines`) and in the second case I'm trying to use the generator to avoid spent this memory with arrays.

Am I using the concept of generators in some wrong way? If not, is it possible achieve it without explode the string and then `yield $expl[$key]`?

I tried to use `substr($string, $pos, strpos($string, PHP_EOL, $pos));` where `$pos` is the position of the string, but I just can call the getLines one time using it.

***INFO:***

PHP 5.6

Comment: Keeping this "very long string" in memory is likely going to cause its own problems in due time. I'd suggest switching `shell_exec()` for [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) and then putting your generator on `yield fgets($pipes[1]);` which is then simply reading lines directly from the command's stdout as it runs.

Comment: Actually, I can't edit the code that return the output  from shell because it is used in many other parts of the system, but thanks for the tip anyway, maybe I try to create a exclusive function for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of how to use a generator when extracting lines from a piece of text.  This has a loop to find the lines one after another and uses `yield` to pass back each segment one at a time..

```
function getLines( $result )    {
    $start = 0;
    while (($end = strpos($result, PHP_EOL, $start)) !== false)   {
        $line = trim(substr($result, $start, $end - $start));
        yield $line;
        $start = $end+1;
    }
}

foreach ( getLines($test) as $line)  {
    echo ">".$line."<".PHP_EOL;
}
```

As you can see, the return value of the function call is used to drive the `foreach` and outputs each line into `$line`.

In this code `$test` is the string to be parsed.